# how to achieve URL re-writing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get re write an aspx URL as follows:

```
.../login.aspx
```

to

```
/login
```

In my web config I have:

```
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="UserFriendlyURLs">
      <add key="/login" value="/login.aspx"/>
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
```

This rule ensures that when the user types

```
/login
```

they are shown the page

```
/login.aspx
```

but the URL stays as

```
login
```

All fine so far.

Now I need it to also go the other way eg when the user types:

```
/login.aspx
```

the URL only shows

```
/login
```

I have tried using:

```
    <rule name="login" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^login.aspx"/>
      <conditions/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="login"/>
    </rule>
```

In my web config, but this gives me a 404 page not found error.

I suspect this is because I am redirecting to a page that is itself a redirected or rewritten URL?

I have also tried:

```
   routes.MapPageRoute("login/", "login", "~/login.aspx");
```

but it also has no effect.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: are you using asp.net 4.0 or higher ?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to use a redirect, not a re write:

```
    <rule name="Login" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^login.aspx$"/>
      <conditions/>
      <action type="Redirect" url="login"/>
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HttpHandler for dynamic URL-Rewriting. This post might helps you.[URL-Rewriting By HTTPHandler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335968/Implementing-HTTPHandler-and-HTTPModule-in-ASP-NET)